# Get value from JPA subentities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can I retrieve the value from childofchild  entity using Spring-data-jpa?

eg. `Person Entity ->Account Entity ->Debit_Account Entity`

Debit Account Entity contains value dbtAmount that I want to retrieve.

I am new in spring and spring-data-jpa repository using find method I cannot get details from childofchild entity.

Comment: Please be careful, if you start a line with 4 (or more) spaces, the editor assumes it is code.  When you create a new question, or edit it, you will see editor help on the right of the screen.  You should take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: You can do this via Inheritance relation betweeen AccountEntity and DebitAccount subentity.

Answer (score 0):

We have to implement the relationships between the entities properly. Such as,

- one to one
- one to many
- many to many

If you have configured this properly you should be able to get person entity, from that get the Account entity using getAccounts method and from that get the DebitAccount using the getDebitAccounts methods.

[JPA Relationship Mapping Concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347766/jpa-relationship-mapping-concept)
https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/

Assuming the relationship are one to many, i have added more explanation,

[image]

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Person {

@Column
private String username;

@Column
private String email;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
private Set<Account> accounts;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Set<Account> getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
}

public void setAccounts(Set<Account> accounts) {
    this.accounts = accounts;
}
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Account {

@Column
String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="account")
private Set<DebitAccount> debitAccounts;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<DebitAccount> getDebitAccounts() {
    return debitAccounts;
}

public void setDebitAccounts(Set<DebitAccount> debitAccounts) {
    this.debitAccounts = debitAccounts;
}

}
```

---

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class DebitAccount {

@Column
String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You didn't add the other side of the mapping, such as the `user` field on the `Account` class and the `account` field on the `DebitAccount` class. If you use `mappedBy` you need to define those as well.